# Error in Python Seaborn Catplot: Object has no len()

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Given some categorical data like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series(["NY", "NY", "CL", "TX", "CL", "FL", "NY", "FL"])
```

In the original data, this is a column in a `DataFrame`. I want to plot it via sns.catplot() like so:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.catplot(x=data, kind="count")
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\PycharmProjects\Troubleshooting\temp.py", line 6, in <module>
    sns.catplot(x=my_data, kind="count")
  File "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Troubleshooting\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 3241, in catplot
    g = FacetGrid(**facet_kws)
  File "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Troubleshooting\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py", line 403, in __init__
    none_na = np.zeros(len(data), bool)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

The `Series` / `Data Frame` has a shape, length etc. so I don't understand where the error message comes from. What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

I know that `sns.countplot()` will work with this input, but I need to use catplot in order to create the countplot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We want questions to be direct and to the point. I [edited the question to remove](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) everything that should not be there.

Comment: Anyway, [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [read the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) for `sns.catplot`? When you do that, what does it say should be the type for the `data` passed in? In particular, does a `pd.Series` qualify?

Comment: Hi @KarlKnechtel, I did. The Seaborn documentation says that (for countplots) the types "names of variables in data or vector data" are valid for use.

Comment: When I go to the web page that I linked you, I see a line that reads "Parameters: data DataFrame". Do you see that? Do you understand the difference between a `Series` and a `DataFrame`?

Comment: That's correct for the data parameter. For the x parameter on the other hand, Seaborn needs a vector.

Comment: Ah, I misread the code example. But then, you see - if you don't pass `data` at all, it will default to `None`, which also isn't a `DataFrame` (and makes the error message much more directly understandable). I have no idea why they default this parameter if it's apparently required. Seems reportable as a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to use a [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with a `Series`, as this higher level function is relevant when multiple columns with categories are present to automatically generate a `FacetGrid`.

Anyway, if you really want to use `catplot`, you'll have to convert to `DataFrame` and pass the data to `data`, not `x` (that is for the **column name** in `data`):

```
sns.catplot(data=data.to_frame('x-label'), x='x-label', kind="count")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @mozway, that is correct. It makes more sense to use it with the entire DataFrame. Thank you for your impulse.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sns.countplot` instead:

```
data = pd.Series(["NY", "NY", "CL", "TX", "CL", "FL", "NY", "FL"])

sns.countplot(x=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thank you guys.

The issue is, that the catplot needs (at least for DataFrames) the explicitly needs parameter "data", given a DataFrame, and then a parameter for "x", but only the column name there. It isn't enough to use the argument "x=df["column_name"]".

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

my_data #any dataframe you have

sns.countplot(data=my_data, x="Column 1", kind="count")
```